How do I make a window of a different application active in Delphi on Windows?
I have a Delphi app where I'd like to have a button that will grab a specific game's window and then make that game's window active. If the game's window is in the background, then it needs to get focused and be brought to the front. I want it to become the active window.
The game I am trying to make active is a DirectX 9 game and it is running in fullscreen borderless windowed mode.

Since you're (presumably) trying to call SendInput(), you'll have to make the target the foreground window. This is a generalized concept of the active window. See Eventually, nothing is special any more to learn about the distinction.

This is as limited as thinking when a window is partly hidden by a different then one isn't able to continue typing text into the former - people tend to need 100% visibility of a window to think only then it will get all the input - they can rarily distinguish between foreground window and active window. You really never had a window set to FormStyle:= fsStayOnTop and realized it didn't steal your input, leaving your other window still active?

Okay. Reading through this link, I've built a procedure to make a window active and it seems to work as far as I can tell.

If you know the Window's Title, then you can use the following procedure to make the window active, and bring it to the front. This works via the SetForegroundWindow function:
uses Winapi.Windows

...

procedure MakeWindowActive(TitleCaption: String);
begin
  var wHandle: hWnd := FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleCaption));
  SetForegroundWindow(wHandle);
end;

I tested this on Portal 2 and it seems to be working great. I use it like this:
MakeWindowActive('PORTAL 2 - Direct3D 9');


And if for some reason, the above procedure doesn't work, then you could also try this alternative:
uses Winapi.Windows

...

procedure MakeWindowActive(TitleCaption: String);
begin
  var wHandle: hWnd := FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleCaption));

  if IsIconic(wHandle) then
     ShowWindow(wHandle, SW_RESTORE)
  else
     BringWindowToTop(wHandle);
end;


But this only works if you know what the game or window's title text is.

No, this doesn't accomplish what you're trying to do. It looks like it's working (because humans generally confuse the top of the Z-order with the foreground window), but once you start calling SendInput() input will go elsewhere.

@IInspectable But how is it not active? Because the game is brought to the front and my mouse is now focused on the game. Meaning that if I move the mouse, then my camera in the game is moving. if I click something on my keyboard and mouse, then it happens in the game. As far as I can tell, the game's window is 100% active.

@ShaunRoselt Most games track hardware/mouse activity at a lower level, regardless of which window actually has input focus. A window being at the front of the z-order, and a window having input focus, are two completely different things. You can use SetForegroundWindow() to bring the window to the front AND give it input focus, but know that function has many restrictions. The OS doesn't like apps stealing focus away from what the user is working on.

@RemyLebeau What would be the correct way to make a window properly active and focused?

@ShaunRoselt see the update to my previous comment

@RemyLebeau Thanks. I've tried SetForegroundWindow and it also works. As far as I can see in terms of how it feels and looks to me, both methods behave the same from a user's perspective. It brings the window to the front and gives it focus for my keyboard and mouse. But I've gone ahead and updated my answer to prefer the SetForegroundWindow method as that does seem to be better from what I read online. Thanks.

@ShaunRoselt FYI, you don't need the StrBuf array in this situation, or the PChar(0) type-cast. You can use FindWindow(nil, PChar(TitleCaption)) instead. You should also make sure FindWindow() actually found the window (ie, wHandle <> 0) before doing anything with wHandle.

@RemyLebeau Interestingly, if I pass a TitleCaption to it that doesn't exist, then there's no error. It just doesn't do anything. So is a wHandle <> 0 check really necessary since there isn't any errors?

The code won't crash, if that is what you mean. But the functions will fail nonetheless, you are just ignoring the failure (don't get in the habit of doing that), and the last error code from GetLastError() will likely be set to ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE (1400).

Good luck with this approach when more than one window fits the searched caption.

@AmigoJack You generally won't launch a game more than once and Source Games actually don't allow you to even launch more than one at a time. How would you suggest doing it instead? This is the only way I could find right now. I want whichever way is the best.

That's not the point - it's enough for one other window handle to have the same title/caption to be a false positive. You should use FindWindowEx(), making sure the HWND is not owned to someone (parent is 0) and to also rely on the class name of a window. Get ahold of EnumWindows() to list all window handles and to see/spot distinctive class names, especially for your game.
